# quadprog in MATLAB taking lot of time

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, svm

My goal is to classify an image using multi class linear SVM (with out kernel). I would like to write my own SVM classifier

I am using MATLAB and have trained linear SVM using image sets provided.

I have around 20 classes, 5 images in each class (total of 100 images) and I am using one-versus-all strategy.

Each image is a (112,92) matrix. That means 112*92=10304 values.

I am using `quadprog(H,f,A,C)` to solve the quadratic equation  (y=w'x+b) in the SVM. One call to `quadprog` returns `w` vector of size 10304  for one image. That means I have to call `quadprog` for 100 times.

**The problem** is one `quadprog` call takes 35 secs to get executed. That means for 100 images it will take 3500 secs. This might be  due to large size of vectors and matrices involved.

**I want to reduce the execution time of `quadprog`. Is there any way to do it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when you do classification using SVM, you usually extract a feature (like HOG) of an image, so that the dimensionality of space on which SVM has to operate gets reduced. You are using raw pixel values, which generates a 10304-D vector. That is not good. Use some standard feature.

Secondly, you do not call `quadprog` 100 times. You call only once. The concept behind the optimization is, you want to find a weight vector `w` and a bias `b` such that it satisfies `w'x_i+b=y_i` for all images (i.e. all x_i). Note that `i` will go from 1 to the number of examples in your training set, but `w` and `b` stay the same. If you wanted a `(w,b)` that will satisfy only one `x`, you do not need any fancy optimization. So stack your `x` in a big matrix of dimension `NxD`, `y` will be a vector of `Nx1`, and then call `quadprog`. It will take a longer time than 35 seconds, but you do it only once. This is called `training an SVM`. While testing for a *new* image, you just extract its feature, and do `w*x+b` to get its class.

Third, unless you are doing this as an exercise to understand SVMs, `quadprog` is not the best way to solve this problem. You need to use some other techniques which work well with large data, for example, [Sequential Minimal Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_minimal_optimization).

**How can one linear hyperplane classify more than 2 classes**: For multi-class classification, SVMs usually use two popular approaches:

1. [One-vs-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification#One-vs.-one) SVM: For a `C` class problem, you train `C(C-1)/2` classifiers and at test time, you test that many classifiers and choose the class which receives most votes.
2. [One-vs-all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification#One-vs.-rest) SVM: As name suggests, you train one classifier per class with positive samples from that class and negative samples from all other classes.

From [LIBSVM FAQs](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f419):

> It is one-against-one. We chose it after doing the following comparison: C.-W. Hsu and C.-J. Lin. A comparison of methods for multi-class support vector machines , IEEE Transactions on Neural Networks, 13(2002), 415-425.
>
> "1-against-the rest" is a good method whose performance is comparable to "1-against-1." We do the latter simply because its training time is shorter.

However, also note that a naive implementation of one-vs-one may not be practical for large-scale problems. LIBSVM website also lists this shortcoming and provides [an extension](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvmtools/#liblinear_for_one_versus_one_multi_class_classification).

> LIBLINEAR does not support one-versus-one multi-classification, so we provide an extension here. If k is the number of classes, we generate k(k-1)/2 models, each of which involves only two classes of training data. According to Yuan et al. (2012), one-versus-one is not practical for large-scale linear classification because of the huge space needed to store k(k-1)/2 models. However, this approach may still be viable if model vectors (i.e., weight vectors) are very sparse. Our implementation stores models in a sparse form and can effectively handle some large-scale data.

Comment: I am using linear SVM classifier and I have 20 classes and say (w'x_i+b) is one hyper plane.  I believe the hyperplane should be a linear one? Could you please throw some information on how can one linear hyper plane be used to classify a test image to which class it may belong to?

Comment: @sravanmummadi If this answered your questions, please upvote and/or accept the answer.